# Printing in color using GSPrint/GhostScript and Python

Tags: python, pdf, printing

I have successfully set everything up to print the files I need, but the default gsprint setting is to print in mono. I am needing them to be in color, but am having trouble finding where to adjust this setting. I found [this article](http://www.ccp14.ac.uk/ccp/web-mirrors/ghostscript/gsview/gsprint.htm) that mentions changing it to print in color, but this is through the command line.

```
GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH = r'C:\GHOSTSCRIPT\bin\gswin32.exe'
GSPRINT_PATH = r'C:\GSPRINT\gsprint.exe'
currentprinter = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

extra code here

win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'gsprint.exe', '-printer "\\\\' + self.server + '\\' + self.printer_name + '" ' + file, '.', 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you just add -color to the command line in there. Eg:

```
win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'gsprint.exe', '-color -printer "\\\\' + self.server + '\\' + self.printer_name + '" ' + file, '.', 0)
```

Does that not work ? Caveat, I am not a Python programmer.....